# Copy Apache2 server from web to local enviroment

Tags: server, apache2, php

I have been developing my website directly on my live server for the past couple of months, and now it is starting to gain a lot of traction.

I want to completely move my server files to a local environment so I can work on an identical set up locally and just transfer my changes to live when I'm done.  I have no idea where to even begin with this!

Any help with how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: My website is using PHP and Laravel 5

Comment: I would suggest to have a look at git, then search a webhoster that provides you with the ability to have test-environments and some deployment mechanism that involves a git-repository that you can push to.

Comment: What are you using to build your site?  Static HTML, PHP, ASP.NET?

Comment: @rclocher3 I am using PHP and Laravel 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using version control.  Basically you'll want to create a git repository for your project and use git in conjunction with a hosting service like [www.github.com](http://github.com) (bitbucket.org, and gitlab.com are a popular alternatives).  Once you get your project setup in a git repository you'll be able to pull a copy down to your development environment, work on it locally (to avoid making breaking changes to the live website), and then when you've completed a change / feature you can test and push it to the live site.

Here is a tutorial on how to add an existing project to github: https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/

Comment: let me mention www.gitlab.com just for completeness (and its open source / open core)

Comment: But when I pull it down from git how do I run it locally?

Comment: How you setup your local development environment is up to you.  A common way to develop laravel projects locally is to use homestead / vagrant: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/homestead

Comment: Alternatively if you use Ubuntu or any other linux distro for your local operating system you can setup a LAMP stack on your local machine and do it that way.  Choice of development environment is very subjective and there are many ways to do it

Comment: Good idea @Phillip-ZyanKLee-Stockmann, i've added it to the answer